# Connecting Canon CanoScan FS4000US USB Scanner to Mac OS 10.7.5

Tags: macos, usb, scanning, canon

I have an old Canon CanoScan FS4000US Slide Scanner. I have connected it via USB to an Intel iMac running Mac OS 10.7.5, and in System Report, I can see that it is connected. Also, when I disconnect and reconnect the USB cable, the slide tray ejects on the scanner. What I would like to know is if there is any way to mount the scanner properly as a device so that it will be available in Image Capture. I downloaded VueScan, a third-party software, that is able to see the device and process a scan, so there must be some way to get the drivers to see the device in Image Capture. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried installing this [comprehensive Apple Canon Printer/Scanner driver set](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL56)?
I dont have an FS400US I can test this with but its worth a shot.

Comment: For whatever reason, I am not able to install this. "Canon Printer Drivers can't be installed on this disk. The volume does not meet the requirements for this update."

Comment: Have you done all the supplemental system updates through system update? Seems like that error throws when there is a model specific update that hasn't been performed.

Comment: Software Update says everything is up to date. I found a newer version of the Canon Printer Driver download, but it hasn't helped either.